# Enable content assist eclipse for Netsuite

Tags: eclipse, netsuite, content-assist

How can I enable autocomplete / content-assist (ctrl+space) in Eclipse for Netsuite? If I create with java content assist work correctly, but if I open and create for Netsuite project content assist doesn't work correctly.
Any one can help?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Download Eclipse Luna from this Link https://www.genuitec.com/luna/. and download **Eclipse Standard 4.4.2** and install it.
 After Installation follow bellow steps.

1. From the Eclipse IDE, click the Help menu then select
   Install New Software…
2. On the Available Software window, add the repository location by clicking on
   the Add button.
3. In Name: type **SuiteCloud IDE**
4. In Location: type **http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update_e4**

**Note**: There are two repository locations depending on the Eclipse                             version you’re using.

• For Eclipse version 3.7 and earlier, use http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update.

• For Eclipse version 3.8 and newer, use http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update_e4

5. In the Work with: field, choose the newly added repository by selecting **SuiteCloud IDE**.
6. This will load up the installation options for the plugin. Put a checkmark on the **SuiteCloud IDE** option.
7. Click Next to view the installation details.
8. Accept the terms of the license agreement and click Finish.
9. Wait for the installation process to complete. Once it’s done, you will be asked to restart Eclipse; just click Yes.

   **Note :**A warning message may appear while installing the plugin. This is normal. Just click OK to continue with the installation
10. You might be prompted to go through the SuiteCloud IDE Setup Wizard. Please cancel this wizard at this point and will be configured in class.

Comment: The instalation has succesfully, but content assist (ctrl+space) didn't work. Can you give me a solution how to enable it?

Comment: Did you have an existing project already that you want to add NetSuite assist? Or did you make a new **NetSuite** project after installing the plugin? The SuiteScript content assist simply comes from adding the SuiteScript API library to your project's build path. You can do this manually in your project's preferences, or you can convert your existing project to a NetSuite project and Eclipse will take care of that part for you.

Comment: I have an existing project and new project also, but content assits still work properly @erictgrubaugh

Comment: I've tried this step @SimonPeter, but still if I use ctrl+space "no netsuite suitescript api"

Answer (score 2):

The documentation up to date says:

> The following table shows the supported versions of Eclipse for each
>   SuiteCloud IDE version:
>
> **SuiteCloud IDE Version**  >>> **Eclipse Version**
>
> 1. **2016.2.0.e4** >>> **4.3.2**
> 2. **2017.1.0**    >>> **4.3.2**

[Here the Source, You must to login into your netsuite account in order to see the content](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N2908702.html)

I was trying to work using eclipse neon 2, but It was impossible to do. So I downloaded the Eclipse Standard Version 4.3.2 and it works fine with the content assist (ctrl+ barspace). [Eclipse Standard Version 4.3.2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-432/keplersr2)

Comment: Same here I was using other eclipse version