# Netsuite Content Assist not working in Eclipse Neon.2

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have recently installed the newest version of Neon.2. Now my content assist for Netsuite is completely missing.

When pressing CTRL+SPACE, I get nothing. Error's stating no proposals at all.

Please let me know what I can. My environment is completely set up the same way as it always has been.

Thank you

Comment: Content assist works for me when I am typing on the function mainline, but when I try to code beyond that I get no proposals.

Comment: Please still looking for a solution. Thanks

Comment: I already answered this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338384/enable-content-assist-eclipse-for-netsuite/44316891#44316891

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this too. But I couldn't find a solution. Then I'd prefer to use to another version of Eclipse.

My Eclipse version: Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issue/difficulty with Eclipse Neon (4.6) while attempting to install the SuiteCloud IDE plugin. The following error was thrown:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=_Users_dsmith_eclipse_jee-neon_Eclipse.app_Contents_Eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). 
>    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api,3.0.0.v20110215-1551

I switched to Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and the plugin installed successfully!